# git-svn: add branches after the fact

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

I've successfully imported a large Subversion repository into git using `git-svn`. It took over four days and I had to help it out by skipping a few revisions.

Unfortunately, I forgot some branches.

The reason is that their structure in the original Subversion hierarchy differs significantly. Here's how *most* branches are laid, roughly:

```
/MainProject // this is the trunk
/MainProject_Branches/SomeBranch
/MainProject_Branches/AnotherBranch
```

This worked fine with `--branches=`.

But also, there's additional branches in an `old` subfolder in that *same* branches folder:

```
/MainProject_Branches/old/AVeryOldBranch
/MainProject_Branches/old/AnotherOldBranch
```

*And* then also, there's a completely different hierarchy:

```
/Customers/SomeCustomer/MainProject_CustomerSpecificFork // this, too, is a branch
/Customers/AnotherCustomer/MainProject_AnotherCustomerSpecificFork // this, too, is a branch
```

I'd like to handle those two scenarios retroactively.

So, one, `git-svn` thought to import the entirety of `/MainProject_Branches/old` as a single branch, which of course doesn't make sense. This is no big deal, but ideally, **I'd like for the incorrect "old" branch to be replaced with the real branches underneath.** (Incidentally, it appears at least SourceTree considers a branch with a slash in its name to be a hierarchy. So even better would be if these could literally be imported in a collapsible sub-branch hierarchy!)

Second and more critically, all the customer-specific forks are missing altogether, since they're in a completely different hierarchy (but in the same SVN repository). I'd like those added after the fact.

Is this possible at all? Do I need a different tool than `git-svn`?